# PHP Curl and Loop based on a numeric value

Tags: php, curl, twitter

Im using the Twitter API to collect the number of tweets I've favorited, well to be accurate the total pages of favorited tweets.

I use this URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/username.xml

I grab the XML element 'favorites_count'

For this example lets assume **favorites_count=5**

The Twitter API uses this URL to get the favorties: http://twitter.com/favorites.xml (Must be authenticated)

You can only get the last 20 favorties using this URL, however you can alter the URL to include a 'page' option by adding: `?page=3` to the end of the favorites URL e.g.

http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=2

So what I need to do is use CURL (I think) to collect the favorite tweets, but using the URL:

```
http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=1

http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=2

http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=3

http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=4

etc...
```

Some kind of loop to visit each URL, and collect the Tweets and then output the cotents.

Can anyone help with this:
- Need to use CURL to authenticate
- Collect the number of pages of tweets (Already scripted this)
- Then use a loop to go through each page URL based on the pages value?

Answer (score 0):

Is favorites_count the total number of favorites or the total number of pages?

```
$twitter = curl_init('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/username.xml');
curl_set_opt($twitter, CUROPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$userInfo = curl_exec($twitter);
$userObj = new SimpleXmlElement($userInfo);
$nbFaves = $userObj->favorites_count; // (string) 5

$urlTpl = "http://http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=%s";
$favorites = array(); // this will be the data for output

for($i =0; $i < $nbFaves; $i++) {
  $pageUrl = sprintf($urlTpl, $i+1); // notice the +1 to move from 0 indexed to 1 indexed
  curl_set_opt($twitter, CURLOPT_URL, $pageUrl);
  $faves = curl_exec($twitter);
  $faves = new SimpleXmlElement($faves);

  foreach($faves->favorite as $fave) {
     $data = array();
     /* here you assign the diferent child values/attributes 
      * from the favorite node to the $data array
      */
     $favorites[] = $data; // push the data array into $favorites
  }

  unset($faves); // just some cleanup

}

// now you would loop through $favorites and output the data as html.
```

Now if `favorites_count` is the total number of favorites and not pages then you need to modify the above to figure out how many pages there are based on how many favorites are on a page. but thats pretty simple.

Comment: favorites_count returns the number of favourites, but I divide that by 20 and the round the number up to get the total number of pages.

Comment: Tried it get call to undefined function.